# In Excel, filling a series of numbers 1 to $n$ without clicking and dragging to the end

Tags: microsoft-excel

I tried googling this but the method of choice is to typically click and drag.

I have a set of data that takes up about 4000 rows. Next to that data, I would like a column from 1 to 4000 and another column of 1's. I know how to click and drag but this seems tedious and inefficient. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2):

You can navigate by keyboard and it's faster. In the name box in the top right, type in the bottom cell you want to fill to (say B4000). When you press enter, it moves your cursor there. Now press ctrl+shift+up arrow and it will select from there up to the cell with the formula. Press Ctrl+D to fill down simply. For more options (for example, increment by one), go to the editing group on the home tab and select fill, then "series..." and you can set your options from there.